# Filter data based on two columns from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '8','4', '1', '2', '4'],
    'start': ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-05-01', '2017-02-01'],
    'end': ['2017-01-02', '2017-02-4', '2017-03-02', '2017-02-06', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-03', '2017-01-06', '2017-04-08', '2017-05-04', '2017-02-01']    
})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2017-01-02', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01'],
    'id': ['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6']       
})
```

I wanted to extract from `df` only the rows where the `id` in `df` matches with `id` in `df1` and the `date` in the `df1` for that specific `id` also matches or falls between the `start` and `end` in the `df`.
I can easily extract the `id` from `df` by comparing if the same `id` is present in the second dataframe `df1` using :

```
df_filtered = df[(df['id'].isin(df1['id']))]
```

but i could not manage to compare `date` of `df1` with the `start` and `end` of `df`. What i wanted as output is the following:

```
  id      start        end
0  1 2017-01-01 2017-01-02
4  3 2017-03-01 2017-03-01
9  4 2017-02-01 2017-02-01
```

date, start and end columns are already in datetime format Y-M-D. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge and filter:

```
df2 = df.merge(df1)
df2[(df2['date']>=df2['start'])&(df2['date']<=df2['end'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df.merge(df1, on='id', how='inner')

        end id       start        date
 0  2017-01-02  1  2017-01-01  2017-01-02
 1   2017-02-4  1  2017-02-01  2017-01-02
 2  2017-04-08  1  2017-04-01  2017-01-02
 3  2017-03-02  2  2017-03-01  2017-02-01
 4  2017-05-04  2  2017-05-01  2017-02-01
 5  2017-02-06  3  2017-02-01  2017-03-01
 6  2017-03-01  3  2017-03-01  2017-03-01
 7  2017-01-06  4  2017-01-01  2017-02-01
 8  2017-02-01  4  2017-02-01  2017-02-01
```

And then compare the columns

Comment: Thanks. Merging both data frames makes life much easier.